# How to extend default angular schematics "ng generate component"

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I need to generate additional stub-* file for each generated component for usage during testing. How can I do that?
I understand that I can create my own schematics by copying default one, buy can I avoid that and gracefully extend default one with additional command for generation an empty stub-* file with the same name as generated component?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ngentest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngentest).
Here is an article how you can use it https://medium.com/allenhwkim/generate-angular-unit-tests-automatically-1300601ed73